# Delayed Job Rails 3 undefined method 'up'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, delayed-job, background-process

I'm trying to resurrect a project from a few months ago using Rails 3.0.7.

I had delayed job working on it previously, but now Ive updated my gems I get the following error when I try and `enqueue` something.

`NoMethodError (undefined method`up' for :null:Symbol):`

The line of code is:

`Delayed::Job.enqueue DelayedXlsExport.new(@email, timestamp, filename)`

DelayedXlsExport is:

```
class DelayedXlsExport < Struct.new(:email, :timestamp, :filename)  
  def perform
    ....
  end
end
```

And here is part of the stack:

> activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in
>   `_run_create_callbacks' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in`create' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:257:in `create_or_update'
>   activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in`block in
>   create_or_update' activesupport (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_save_callbacks'
>   activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in`
>   create_or_update' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:40:in `save' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in`save' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save' activerecord
>   (3.0.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in`block (2 levels) in
>   save' activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in
>   `block in with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in`
>   transaction' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction' activerecord
>   (3.0.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in`
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block in save' activerecord
>   (3.0.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in`
>   rollback_active_record_state!' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save' activerecord (3.0.10)
>   lib/active_record/base.rb:504:in`create'
>   C:/dev/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/delayed_job-8efc2aa99e8b/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:28:in
>   `enqueue'

My gem file:

`gem "delayed_job", :branch => 'v2.1', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'`

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the workless gem fixed this issue

`gem 'workless', '0.2.0'`